# Hexagonal grid in ios

Tags: ios, image, swift, core-graphics

I am new to iOS i want to make hexagonal grid(Honeycomb like)for a game. I just want to know whether  to use core graphics to draw hexagons or to use hexagon image to make hexagonal grid which is better.

Comment: Better in performance

Comment: Try both and profile with Instruments...

Answer (score 0):

Try the simplest way you can think of that works. If there is no performance problem you are done. If there is a performance problem try another solution.

Comment: I tried using images but it takes time(approx 7-8 sec) to load grid view

Comment: Great, now try something else. Or post your code and maybe someone can see a way to make it faster.